# JavaScript implementation of printing left view of binary tree is returning incorrect result

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, binary-tree

I am trying to print the left view of a binary tree as seen [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-left-view-binary-tree/) on geeksforgeeks. For some reason it isn't working, I suspect it has to do with `max_level`. The result is `[ 12, 10, 30, 25, 40 ]` and I'm expecting `[12,10,25]`.

## JS Code

```
var Node = function(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.left = this.right = null;
};

var leftViewUtil = function(root, level, max, result) {
    if (root === null) return;

    if (max.level < level) {
        max.level = level;
        result.arr.push(root.val);
    }

    leftViewUtil(root.left, ++level, max, result);
    leftViewUtil(root.right, ++level, max, result);
};

var leftView = function(root) {
    var result = {
        arr: []
    };

    var max_level = {level: 0};

    leftViewUtil(root, 1, max_level, result);

    return result.arr;
};

root = new Node(12);
root.left = new Node(10);
root.right = new Node(30);
root.right.left = new Node(25);
root.right.right = new Node(40);

var run = function() {
    console.log(leftView(root));
};

run();
```

Comment: When you're translating code you shouldn't remove the comments :-)

Comment: coding practice from Facebook interview prep, `number of visible nodes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the code on the linked page is

> ```
> // Recur for left and right subtrees
> leftViewUtil(root->left, level+1, max_level);
> leftViewUtil(root->right, level+1, max_level);
> ```

vs

> ```
> leftViewUtil(root.left, ++level, max, result);
> leftViewUtil(root.right, ++level, max, result);
> ```

You are increasing `level` twice here, while you should pass the same value to both recursive calls. Either use `level+1` as proper, or do the increment before the calls:

```
++level;
leftViewUtil(root.left, level, max, result);
leftViewUtil(root.right, level, max, result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Hash table find left and right view of tree in few lines of code.

```
right_view(root,num, result) {
    if(root == null) {
        return 0
    }
    right_view(root.Left, num+1, result)
    right_view(root.Right, num+1, result)
    result[num] = root.Value
}

left_view(root,num, result) {
    if(root == null) {
        return 0
    }
    left_view(root.Left, num+1, result)
    left_view(root.Right, num+1, result)
    if(result[num] == undefined) {
        result[num] = root.Value
    }
}
```

## Calling function with root node.

```
right_view_result = {}
right_view(root,1,right_view_result)
console.log(right_view_result)
```

## Calling function with root node.

```
left_view_result = {}
left_view(root,1,left_view_result)
console.log(left_view_result)
```